# deleting all the <br> tags at the end of a span

Tags: jquery, html

When I displaying a text, there is always some br tags at the end of the tags, and the number of  br tags may change time. I checked resources, but could not figure it out for me. Below is a sample span tag from my page.

How can I clear these indefinite number of br tags at the end? I am using Jquery. And, I do not want to remove the br tags within the text, but at the end of the text.

```
<span class="small comment-display-label">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;You are correct in the idea that cilia and flagella serve similar general function (motility) but differ in length and rate of movement. <br> evolutionary advantage of flagella for prokaryotes stem from the type of movement that is necessary, the specialized rotating function would be useful to prokaryotes for more advanced movement and selection of foward or backward movement.&nbsp;<br>See:&nbsp;<a target="_blank" href="http://micro.magnet.fsu.edu/cells/ciliaandflagella/ciliaandflagella.html">http://micro.magnet.fsu.edu/cells/ciliaandflagella/ciliaandflagella.html<br></a><br><br><br><br></span>
```

Comment: u may use regex to replace end <br> s

Comment: You have a `<br>` before `</a>`. This leads me to guess that it could be the work of the editor you are using. Did you check to see if your editor adds `<br>` tags each time you press Enter?

Comment: Where do these `br` tags come from? Are you outputting a value in PHP? If so, maybe it's better to trim enters from the value before converting it to HTML and outputting it.

Comment: I am using asp.net c#. Yes, I think when users post sth they press "enter" a lot, which creates these extra br tags at the end. But, I do not mind users do that. I just want not to display these extra breaks in the output. How can I remove them using jquery?